# What's the meaning of #inst "2000" and the concept behind it in (clojrue.spec/inst-in #inst "2000" #inst "2010")

Tags: clojure, clojure.spec

I'm study clojure.spec, and ran into the following:

```
(s/def ::the-aughts (s/inst-in #inst "2000" #inst "2010"))
```

I guess that `#inst "2000"` might mean an instance of time at the beginning of year 2000. But I couldn't find, by google, the proper documentation describing the notation, and the concept behind it.

I hadn't learned in my Clojure textbooks either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This syntax is called ["tagged literals"](https://github.com/edn-format/edn#tagged-elements). It allows extending [EDN](https://github.com/edn-format/edn) with your own types. [Clojure reader supports it](http://clojure.org/reference/reader#_tagged_literals) and provides a mechanism to map a tag literal to a function what will produce an actual value.

Instant tag literal (`#inst`) maps to a [date parsed from the string](https://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.instant-api.html#clojure.instant/parse-timestamp). You can find more information in [the cookbook](https://github.com/clojure-cookbook/clojure-cookbook/blob/master/01_primitive-data/1-26_reader-literal.asciidoc) and [Clojure changelog](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/changes.md#211-instant-literals).